# Expected Google Compute health check interval

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a health check with a 1-second check interval (http://s.drollette.com/0B2A3Z1w2X1G). It was created by the GLBC Ingress controller in kubernetes. But looking at the logs it appears that it is generating 3 requests per second (http://s.drollette.com/2U432C2f1d2f). Is this expected behavior from a Google Compute Health Check? Nothing else is configured to be hitting that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. More than one health checker is used to check the service, and each health checker independently obeys the interval specified in your configuration.